# Android: How to run and stop multiple threads from Main Activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I am running a service by pressing start button. In service a main thread is run in which I am taking phone number from db. 
After taking data I have to do some task with diffrent intervals of time. For that I use schedule to which run after **20 second pause**. During that pause I am calling my **doMyWork()  (function)** after 2 second pause.

The problems I am facing are when 20 second schedule complete its cycle the **doMyWork()** function is call twice, thrice....and so on.
Secondly when I stop my service from activity the **OnDestroy** method stop my service and MainThread but did not stop for loop until it execute 30 times.

The code is

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // The service is being created
    myThread.run();
}

private Runnable MainThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        try {
            Cursor c = db.getNumbers(); // DB operation
            scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
            // This schedule a runnable task every 20 seconds
            scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                        Thread.sleep(2000); // Wait 2 Seconds 
                        Log.v(TAG, "  wait" + i );

                        doMyWork(); // perform this operation
                    }// for
                }
            },  0, 20 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
};      
Thread myThread = new Thread( MainThread);



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdown();
    myThread.stop();
}
```

Please give me advice how to use muliple timers sequentialy in thread.

**EDIT**

What I wanted to do is to run loop code.
Let say Loop is having 20 iterations and in each cycle loop wait for 2 seconds before executing **doMyWork()** . 
The scheduleTaskExecutor timer is variable not fix value . Let say if I give it a value 10 second.
Then it should go to for loop run doMyWork() function with 2 second pause.

It means when for loop run (i= 1,2,..5) 5 times scheduleTaskExecutor (5 x 2 = 10) should stop for 10 seconds.

After wait is should run the loop from (i = 6,7,...10) iteration.

Iterations:

```
scheduleTaskExecutor     Step 0
 run
 {
    loop i = 0  till 20   Step 1
      wait 2 seconds     Step 2
       doMyWork()        Step 3 
    loop i = 1  
      wait 2 seconds
       doMyWork()
    loop i = 2  
      wait 2 seconds
       doMyWork()
    loop i = 3  
      wait 2 seconds
       doMyWork()
    loop i = 4  
      wait 2 seconds
       doMyWork()
    loop i = 5  
      wait 5 seconds
       doMyWork()
}
```

scheduleTaskExecutor  Wait 10 Step 4

After step 4 Again go to step 1

Answer (score 1):

You are running said loop every 20 seconds.

And in loop you are running a routine 30 times, every 2 seconds.

So it takes 30 x 2 seconds to execute loop. (60 seconds)

20 seconds into the first loop, you are starting a new loop..

So at 20 seconds from creation you have :

```
Loop 1 20/60 seconds complete.
Loop 2 0/60 seconds complete.
```

So every 2 seconds, `doMyWork()` is running twice.

after 40 seconds, you have:

```
Loop 1 40/60 seconds complete.
Loop 2 20/60 seconds complete.
Loop 3 0/60 seconds complete.
```

so every 2 seconds, `doMyWork()` is running thrice.

and so on.

in terms of your final question, you need to tell the Runnable to stop, on destroy. So will need a global variable to do this so you can access the Runnable.